# no me saltan las alarmas en el movil pero si en el emulador de android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

que tal. Tengo ese problema que describo en el titulo. Las alarmas saltan correctamente en el emulador de android pero al ejecutarlo en el movil no saltan. Tendria que mandar un toast con el mensaje "salto la alarma" pero el mensaje nunca salta.
La estructura es la siguiente: creo en el mainActiviy un objeto de la clase Alarma, que es una clase que he definido yo, y en esa clase se crea el AlarmManager que deberia crear la alarma, y lanzar el onReceive del broadcast receiver.
Este es el codigo completo:
MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Alarma alarmaMensual=new Alarma(getApplicationContext(),"pastilla","mensual",2022, 2,17,17,41,00,1,1,null);
    }
}
```

clase Alarma: (hay muchos campos que no se utilizan ya que esta es una adaptacion minimizada de la aplicacion que tengo real)

```
public class Alarma {
    private int ano;
    private int mes;
    private int dia;
    private int hora;
    private int minuto;
    private int segundo;
    private String pastilla;
    private String frecuencia;
    private Context contexto;
    private int nMinutos;
    private int weekOfYear;
    private String parteDeldia;
    private int requestID;
    private AlarmManager aMan;

    public Alarma(Context contexto, String pastilla, String frecuencia, int ano, int mes, int dia, int hora, int minuto, int segundo, int nMinutos, int requestID, String parteDelDia) {
        this.pastilla=pastilla;
        this.frecuencia=frecuencia;
        this.ano = ano;
        this.mes = mes;
        this.dia = dia;
        this.hora = hora;
        this.minuto = minuto;
        this.segundo = segundo;
        this.contexto=contexto;
        this.nMinutos=nMinutos;
        this.parteDeldia=parteDelDia;
        this.requestID=requestID;

        crearAlarma(contexto,ano,mes,dia,hora,minuto,segundo,requestID);
    }

    public Calendar crearCalendario(int ano, int mes, int dia, int hora, int minuto, int segundo)
    {

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        cal.set (Calendar.YEAR, ano);
        cal.set (Calendar.MONTH, mes);
        cal.set (Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dia);
        cal.set (Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hora);
        cal.set (Calendar.MINUTE, minuto);
        cal.set (Calendar.SECOND, segundo);
        return cal;
    }
    public void crearAlarma(Context contexto,int ano,int mes,int dia,int hora, int minuto,int segundo,int requestID) {
        String fecha =ano+"-"+mes+"-"+dia;
        Intent intentoLanzar = new Intent(contexto.getApplicationContext(), com.example.pruebaalarma.Temporizador.class);
        intentoLanzar.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        Calendar calendario= crearCalendario(ano,mes,dia,hora,minuto,segundo);
        PendingIntent pIntent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(contexto, requestID, intentoLanzar, 0);
        aMan = (AlarmManager)contexto.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        //aMan.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendario.getTimeInMillis(), pIntent);
        aMan.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendario.getTimeInMillis(), 1000*60*nMinutos, pIntent);
        //Toast.makeText(contexto, "hola", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

este es el broacdast receiver:

```
public class Temporizador extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private Context contexto;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)  {
        Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(),"salto la alarma", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

y este el android manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.pruebaalarma">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.PruebaAlarma">
        <receiver
            android:name=".Temporizador"
            android:process=":remote" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Tal vez sea que no tienes activos los permisos adecuados en el movil para que la app muestre alertas

Comment: el caso es que no encuentro por ningun sitio los permisos de la alarma o del despertador.